# Sending POST response to client to be displayed by an html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a button in `index.html` page

**index.html**

```
<form action="/view" method="POST">
    <input type = "email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" name = "emailView" id = "txtEmailView">
    <input type = "submit" id = "btnView" value = "View Application" >
</form>
```

When the button is pressed, I read a database to retrieve some data like below.

**aws.js**

```
app.post('/view', function(req, res) {
    //need to read from database
    var email = req.body.emailView;
    var paramsRead = {
        TableName: tableNameShopper,
        Key:{
            "email": email
        }
    };

    readFromTable(paramsRead).then((results) => {
        var objShopper = JSON.parse(results);
            if(results =="{}"){
          //nothing to do
        }
        else{

         //send response from here
        }

      });

  });
```

Now I need to send the response of the read to a different client `view.html`, not to `index.html`. How do I do that?

**view.html**

```
<input type = "text" placeholder="First Name" name = "fname" id = "viewFirstName"><br><br>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Last Name" name = "lname" id = "viewLastName"><br><br>
<input type = "email" placeholder="Email" name = "email" id = "viewEmail"><br><br>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Phone" name = "phone" id = "viewPhone"><br><br>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Zip Code" name = "zip" id = "viewZip"><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to redirect the response to someone else. That isn't how HTTP works.

Instead `aws.js` will just respond with `success` or `failure` or just `finished` back to `index.html`, whether it may care about if it works or not and what it should move on to doing, if anything. *Before* sending that response back to `index.html` though, you'll want to trigger whatever events end up getting the appropriate information to `view.html`.

You can do that in basically two ways, but they'll both start the same way. You must put a record in some db somewhere that says 'hey, this happened, and here's what index.html sent me'. Then you can handle it one of two ways:

1. Have `view.html` constantly GETing another endpoint that just looks at the db and returns the information from `index.html` if it's just been inserted, or returns 'sorry, no new information yet' if `index.html` hasn't been submitted yet.
2. Have `view.html` open a websocket to another endpoint on your server that either monitors the database for new records or can be directly notified by `aws.js` when something gets submitted, this websocket endpoint can then send a message directly to the client with the appropriate information.